# Using the Data.Vector.Generic interface

Tags: haskell, vector

I'm having some trouble defining the type signature when using the generic vector interface. I want to construct a method that can work on both boxed and unboxed vectors.

This works, but is constrained to boxed vectors:

```
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Data.Vector                 as V
import           Data.Vector.Generic         as VG
import           Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as VGM
import           Data.Vector.Mutable         as VM
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM

mySwap :: V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
mySwap vec = runST $ do
  vec_mut <- V.thaw vec
  VM.swap vec_mut 0 1
  V.unsafeFreeze vec_mut
```

If I change `V` to `VG` in order to use the generic interface, then two arguments are needed for the vector in the type signature, but I'm not sure how to constrain the first argument:

```
mySwap2 :: VG.Vector v a -> VG.Vector v a
mySwap2 vec = runST $ do
  vec_mut <- VG.thaw vec
  VGM.swap vec_mut 0 1
  VG.unsafeFreeze vec_mut
```

> Expected a type, but `VG.Vector v a` has kind
>   `ghc-prim-.4.0.0:GHC.Prim.Constraint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Generic` module, `Vector` is a type class and needs to be used as a constraint, e.g.:

```
mySwap2 :: VG.Vector v a => v a -> v a
```

This means: `v` is some kind of vector which is capable of holding `a`s.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the type signature and let GHC guide me:

```
gswap v = runST $ do
  vmut <- VG.thaw v
  VGM.swap vmut 0 1
  VG.unsafeFreeze vmut
```

At first this yielded:

```
Illegal equational constraint Mutable v ~ Mutable v
(Use GADTs or TypeFamilies to permit this)
```

After adding `LANGUAGE TypeFamilies` it compiled and `:t gswap` returned:

```
gswap
  :: (VG.Vector v a, VG.Vector v1 a, Mutable v1 ~ Mutable v) =>
     v a -> v1 a
```

But if `v` and `v1` are the same type the mutable constraint is trivially satisfied and you don't need the TypeFamilies extension.

Comment: Let GHC be your friend. Also look up [partial type signatures](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures) to have GHC tell you what part of a type signature should be.